# Android retrofit handle onFailure() response

Tags: android, retrofit

I have been developing android app, wheream using **Retrofit**.

In that how to handle `onFailure(Throwable t)` callback for **NoInternetConnection** and **OtherError**

I have check some questions on stackoverflow, but it didn't helped, because am using **retrofit 2**

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
```

**Callback Code**

```
    public class AvsCallBack<T> implements Callback<T> {
        private static final String TAG = "AvsCallBack";
        private AvsCallbackInterface<T> avsInterface;
        private Activity activity;
        private boolean validateError = true;

        public AvsCallBack(Activity activity, AvsCallbackInterface<T> avsInterface) {
            this.activity = activity;
            this.avsInterface = avsInterface;
        }

        public AvsCallBack(Activity activity, AvsCallbackInterface<T> avsInterface, boolean validateError) {
            this.activity = activity;
            this.avsInterface = avsInterface;
            this.validateError = validateError;
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<T> call, Response<T> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, new Gson().toJson(response.body()));
                avsInterface.onSuccess(call, response.body());
            } else {
                onFailure(call, null);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<T> call, Throwable t) {
            if (validateError) {
                if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                    Log.d(TAG, "Retrofit Exception -> " + ((t != null && t.getMessage() != null) ? t.getMessage() : "---"));
                if (t != null && (t instanceof IOException || t instanceof SocketTimeoutException || t instanceof ConnectException)) {
                    if (t instanceof SocketTimeoutException || t instanceof TimeoutException) {
                        ((BaseActivity) activity).showToast("Oops something went wrong");
                        //avsInterface.onError(call, new AvsException("Oops something went wrong, please try again later..."));
                    } else {
                        ((BaseActivity) activity).showToast("Please check your internet connection...");
                        //avsInterface.onError(call, new AvsException("Please check your internet connection..."));
                    }
                } else {
                   ((BaseActivity) activity).showToast("Oops something went wrong");
                }
                if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                    Log.d(TAG, "Avs Exception -> " + ((t != null && t.getMessage() != null) ? t.getMessage() : "---"));
            }
            avsInterface.onError(call, t);
        }
    }
```

**MyInterface**

```
public interface AvsCallbackInterface<T> {

    void onSuccess(Call<T> call, T t);

    void onError(Call<T> call, Throwable throwable);
}
```

Comment: Make your own checking for internet connection and don't start request. Is bad for memory and you waste process. For server errors, cast exception to `HttpException` from Retrofit package.

Comment: I indeed checked internet scenario before starting service and it will popup "no internet msg", but what if network problem arises once after service called?

Comment: Will return 'SocketTimeoutException`. I think.. Or something about your endpoint, that can't be reached.

Comment: At that time you will receive UnknowHostException in **onFailure** method.

Answer (score 4):

Quote from [here](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1260):

> When `Throwable` is passed to the failure, the callback is an
>   `IOException`, this means that it was a network problem (socket
>   timeout, unknown host, etc.). Any other exception means something
>   broke either in serializing/deserializing the data or it's a
>   configuration problem.
>
> You can do `t instanceof IOException` to determine network problem and
>   react appropriately.
>
> A 401 (or any non-2xx response code) will actually go to the response
>   callback, because it was a successful response even though it may not
>   have been a successful operation on the server. You can check this in
>   `onResponse` by calling `response.isSuccess()`.

Comment: In IOException how can I check that its due to internet connection or some other timeout

Comment: try to check internet connection availability inside onFailure() which is not at all a straight forward method.

Answer (score 3):

What I do is use a interceptor for request which checks for internet connectivity and responds accordingly. In my case I use MPV so it automatically call BasePresenter method.

Interceptor:

```
class NetworkStatusInterceptor implements Interceptor {

        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            if (!Util.isInternet(mContext)) {
              return new Response.Builder()
                      .code(1007)
                      .request(chain.request())
                      .protocol(Protocol.HTTP_2)
                      .body(ResponseBody.create(MediaType.parse("{}"),"{}"))
                      .message(mContext.getString(R.string.warning_no_internet))
                      .build();
            }
            return chain.proceed(chain.request());
        }
    }
```

Attach interceptor to OkHTTPClient:

```
 builder.addInterceptor(new NetworkStatusInterceptor());
```

You can handle this in your onResponse:

```
public void onResponse(final Call<T> call, final Response<T> response) {
        if (response.code() == 1007) {
          // handle no internet error
       }
    }
```